# How to create an array tree based on path-style values?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a problem with multidimensional data arrays. I have a data array like this:

```
[
    [
        "name" => "netSnmp",
        "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072"
        "status" => "current"
    ], [
        "name" => "netSnmpObjects",
        "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1"
    ], [
        "name" => "netSnmpEnumerations",
        "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.3"
    ], [
        "name" => "netSnmpModuleIDs",
        "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.3.1"
    ], [
        "name" => "netSnmpAgentOIDs",
        "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.3.2"
    ], [
        "name" => "netSnmpDomains",
        "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.3.3"
    ], [
        "name" => "netSnmpNotificationPrefix",
        "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.4"
    ], [
        "name" => "netSnmpNotifications",
        "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.4.0"
    ], [
        "name" => "netSnmpNotificationObjects",
        "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.4.1"
    ]
]
```

I am looking for a simple way to create an array *tree*, based on the `oid` value from the array above. Those `oid` values are a dot-separated path. The more parts, the deeper in the final tree the corresponding item should be put.

The desired output:

```
[
    "text" => "netSnmp",
    "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072",
    "nodes" => [
        [
            "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1",
            "text" => "netSnmpObjects"
        ], [
            "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.3",
            "text" => "netSnmpEnumerations",
            "nodes" => [
                [
                    "text" => "netSnmpModuleIDs",
                    "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.3.1"
                ], [
                    "text" => "netSnmpAgentOIDs",
                    "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.3.2"
                ], [
                    "text" => "netSnmpDomains",
                    "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.3.3"
                ]
            ]
        ], [
            "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.4",
            "text" => "netSnmpNotificationPrefix"
            "nodes" => [
                [
                    "text" => "netSnmpNotifications",
                    "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.4.0"
                ], [
                    "text" => "netSnmpNotificationObjects",
                    "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.4.1"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Any idea how I can solve it?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? What's the criteria to group things for this example?

Comment: Thanks @Mihail Minkov, I want to make a tree arrangement based on oid values

Comment: Could you update your question with the tree hierarchy rules regarding oid that way it would be more useful for people to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can key your data by `oid` in a new associated array: that way you can look up a certain parent key in a fast way.

Then it is just a matter of getting the parent key of a any given key (chopping off the final dot-separated part) and see where you have it in your new associated array, and then appending it to its `nodes` array.

Here is a function that does that:

```
function makeTree($arr) {
    $keyed = [];
    foreach ($arr as $item) $keyed[$item["oid"]] = $item;
    $root = null;
    
    foreach ($keyed as &$item) {
        $key = $item["oid"];
        $parent = substr($key, 0, strrpos($key, "."));
        if (isset($keyed[$parent])) {
            $keyed[$parent]["nodes"][] =& $item;
        } else {
            $root = $key;
        }
    }
    return $keyed[$root];
}
```

You can run it like this on your sample data:

```
$arr = [
    [
        "name" => "netSnmp",
        "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072",
        "status" => "current"
    ], [
        "name" => "netSnmpObjects",
        "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1"
    ], [
        "name" => "netSnmpEnumerations",
        "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.3"
    ], [
        "name" => "netSnmpModuleIDs",
        "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.3.1"
    ], [
        "name" => "netSnmpAgentOIDs",
        "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.3.2"
    ], [
        "name" => "netSnmpDomains",
        "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.3.3"
    ], [
        "name" => "netSnmpNotificationPrefix",
        "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.4"
    ], [
        "name" => "netSnmpNotifications",
        "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.4.0"
    ], [
        "name" => "netSnmpNotificationObjects",
        "oid" => "1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.4.1"
    ]
];

$result = makeTree($arr);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: This function works well, and now I can develop it according to my needs. thank you very much for help.